# Google PageSpeed "Ensure text remains visible" with 0ms potential saving

Tags: html, angular, seo, font-face, pagespeed

[Image reference of the 0ms potential saving message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/erXZy.png)

I keep getting this warning in Google PageSpeed and now I'm totally out of ideas. I'm using the following code to set the font-family:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
    font-display: swap;
    font-weight: 500;
    src: url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:wght@300;400;500;700;900&display=swap");
}
```

I also have the `rel="preconnect"` in my index.html for both Google Fonts related URL.

Why do I get this warning, when the potential saving is zero?

Answer (score 1):

The error in the image indicates a missing `font-display` setting for your font-family. Looking at the code you posted do have one tho.

But the way youre loading the google fonts isnt correct at all and may cause this issue.

What youre doing is importing the whole google fonts css (https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:wght@300;400;500;700;900&display=swap) into the `src` attribute of your font-family.

Problem is:
If you look at https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:wght@300;400;500;700;900&display=swap you'll see it already contains all the font families so you should just use it like this

```
@import https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:wght@300;400;500;700;900&display=swap
```

or even import it in your html `head` directly:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:wght@300;400;500;700;900&display=swap">
```

To make things more clear heres how https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Roboto?query=roboto advises you to import the files:

> To embed a font, copy the code into the  of your html

a) "link Tag"

> `<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com"> <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin> <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:wght@300;400;500;700;900&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">`

b) @import

> `<style> @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:wght@300;400;500;700;900&display=swap'); </style>`

CSS rules to specify families

> `font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;`

Comment: I'm not 100% sure what you mean by "importing the whole google fonts css into the src attribute". If I rewrite the file to @import the font, intellisense starts to complain about the font-family not having an src property. What is the difference between importig the font from an url, and providing the same url as src?

Comment: The `src` property of a font-family should point to an actual font file. For example (copied from https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:wght@300;400;500;700;900&display=swap): `src: url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v29/KFOlCnqEu92Fr1MmSU5fCRc4EsA.woff2) format('woff2');` while in your code it points to a CSS file (the google fonts css) which declares several font-families itself.

Comment: @Marcell ive updated my answer to make things more clear.

Comment: I've changed my code to match your answer, but I'm getting the exact same results from PageSpeed.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out one of my packages (@agm/core) caused this issue. After removing it, PageSpeed no longer indicated the problem.